# Migrating multiple `.tfstate` & `.tfvars` files to a `s3` backend

Tags: migration, terraform

I have a large legacy terraform setup that uses multiple local `.tfvars` to represent multiple stacks. These stacks in turn have a `.tfstate` to represent them. The structure of the terraform project looks like this

```
.
└── master
    └── apps
        ├── environments
        │   ├── eu
        │   │   ├── eu-prod
        │   │   │   ├── eu-prod.tfstate
        │   │   │   ├── eu-prod.tfstate.backup
        │   │   │   └── eu-prod.tfvars
        │   │   └── eu-staging
        │   │       ├── eu-staging.tfstate
        │   │       ├── eu-staging.tfstate.backup
        │   │       └── eu-staging.tfvars
        │   └── us
        │       ├── us-prod
        │       │   ├── us-prod.tfstate
        │       │   ├── us-prod.tfstate.backup
        │       │   └── us-prod.tfvars
        │       └── us-staging
        │           ├── us-staging.tfstate
        │           ├── us-staging.tfstate.backup
        │           └── us-staging.tfvars
        ├── main.tf
        ├── outputs.tf
        ├── other_resources.tf
        ├── variables.tf
        └── versions.tf
```

In this case you can see we have 4 primary "environments" (or stacks). `eu-prod`, `eu-staging`, `us-prod` and `us-staging`. The base `.tf` files, however, are in `master/apps`. That's the actual HCL used to create each stack. The only thing that varies between stacks is sizes, names, and other vars. We use the cli arguments to specify which set of `.tfvars` to use and which `.tfstate` to write to. An example of that would look like this (run from `master/apps`:

`terraform apply -var-file=./environments/eu/eu-prod/eu-prod.tfvars -state=./environments/eu/eu-prod/eu-prod.tfstate`

What's the best way to go about migrating this to a remote backend like the `s3` backend? I've been able to set the `s3` backend in `main.tf` by doing

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket               = "foobar-terraform-state"
    key                  = "foobar/terraform.tfstate"
    region               = "us-west-1"
    dynamodb_table       = "foobar-terraform-state-lock"
    encrypt              = true
  }
}
```

However I can't figure out how to distinguish between the different stacks. I can set the `.tfvars` for each stack but am unable to specify the keyname dynamically.

Comment: Can you explain some in the question how you were previously specifying the stacks? I assume just with `-var-file` and `-state` but I think showing your existing commands would be helpful.

Comment: Exactly that! I've updated the question to reflect that.